# how to get sim info using cordova-plugin in android

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I’m trying to implement the DeviceInformationPlugin from https://github.com/vliesaputra/DeviceInformationPlugin and I’m confused on how to display the user’s sim card information through android(Web Application)

On the github website, I was given the following piece of code to Use

```
var deviceInfo = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/DeviceInformation");
deviceInfo.get(function(result) {
    console.log("result = " + result);
}, function() {
    console.log("error");
});
```

And I used to logcat in android to view my results however, there are no results to view. Please Help me.

Comment: Try to use alert when you debug on your device. Maybe it could give you more information.

Comment: but wouldn't alerts work with html, because we currently using Javascript, and no form of data is being passed to the html in relation to the deviceInfo.